# Mocha is copying value of object thus cannot update it

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I am running Mocha UT Framework + supertest + chai.

I've the following function that I run :

```
function Test1(inputObj) {
    return function(done) {
       ...
       require
       .post('...')
       .expect(302)
       .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          inputObj.id = 'someIdFromResponse';
          console.log('after update: ', inputObj); // inputObj includes id
          done();
    }
}

    function Test2(inputObj) {
      return function(done) { 
        console.log('Test2.inputObj: ', inputObj); // no id is printed!
        done();
       }
     }
```

Running the following Mocha step:

```
var globalInputObj = { name: 'test' };

describe('test suite 1\n', function() {
    it('should add id to input obj', Test1(globalInputObj));
    it('only prints the globalInputObj', Test2(globalInputObj));
}
...
// this line runs after the describe function, guaranteed!
console.log('globalInputObj: ', globalInputObj); // no id field in object
```

The **globalInputObject** isn't updated after the test function runs, although it is passed by reference.

What am I missing here? and any ideas to solve this?

Comment: All you've done is return a function when you call `Test1(globalInputObj)`. To run the returned function you would have to call it like this: `Test1(globalInputObj)();`. All your test is currently doing is calling `Test1`, passing in your `inputObj`, and getting back an anonymous function. Inside that function you modify `inputObj`, but you never call the returned function so there's no way it would actually perform the modification.

Comment: I tried to post ^that^ as an answer but I keep getting ["An error occurred submitting the answer."](http://i.imgur.com/R5CSApD.png) for some reason :/

Comment: @AlexFord Yes, `Test1` returns an anonymous function. That's true. However, the solution is not to immediately call this anonymous function. Under normal operating conditions, Mocha's `it` will call the function.

Comment: @AlexFord, this is not the problem, the function is being run. I added console.log (also modified my question) you can see.

Comment: Ah my mistake. I believe the issue is that an object isn't actually passed by reference if it's referenced in a closure. It's tied to that scope chain and becomes a new instance, not affecting the object passed in from a higher scope.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/wnIxg?editors=001 <-- confirmed; by referencing the object from within a closure it becomes a new object and no longer refers to the original. Still can't post an answer for some reason though. Strange considering I just posted one 20 minutes ago on another question.

Comment: @AlexFord Objects are passed by reference. The reason you did not update is because the "closure" returns a function for which you never called and therefore never added the property to the second object.

Comment: @AlexFord you assign TWO different objects passing the later into a function that returns a function that NEVER gets called! Hence any logic in the inner "closure'd" function NEVER gets executed.

Comment: Nevermind. You're right. I was stupid and didn't invoke my own returned function. You guys are correct about the issue. EDIT: @Sukima, I made a mistake. Take a chill pill. Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
console.log('globalInputObj: ', globalInputObj); // no id field in object
```

which you've put after your `describe` call executes *before* any tests are run. So it is not surprising that you don't get the results you want. In the edit to your question you show a sequence of `it` calls where one `it` call depends on the previous one. This is not the correct way to set your tests. The proper way to use Mocha is to make sure each test is independent of another test. Any initialization code should be in `before` or `beforeEach` hooks. On the basis of your updated question, you could structure your tests like this:

```
describe('test suite 1\n', function() {
    // Initialize a test object.
    var inputObj = { name: 'test' };

    // The before hook gets
    before(function (done) {
        ...
        require
        .post('...')
        .expect(302)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            inputObj.id = 'someIdFromResponse';
            done();
        }
    });

    it('should add id to input obj', function () {
        assert.equal(inputObj.id, 'someIdFromResponse');
    });

    it('only prints the globalInputObj', function () {
        console.log('inputObj: ', inputObj);
    });
}
```

I've use `assert.equal` above to perform the assertion. You can use any assertion library you like.

Comment: Indirection via the `Test1` method can be a little misleading and confusing. Better to place the setup in a beforeEach function, test and expectations in the it function.

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't only me having issues.

Comment: okay, this works! but if i put another it() right after the first one, the value of globalInputObj isn't updated in the 2nd it (see updated question above)!!! what I am trying to do is dependent it statements. The 1st it('Create object and save the created id', CreateObj(globalObj)); , the 2nd one is it('Destroy object, but no need to figure out the id because it was saved by create in the passed parameter', destroyObj(globalObj)); . The question is, is it a good practice to put the destroy in after() function? I don't think so, maybe I want to do things before I call the after.

Comment: thanks makes sense, last question: is it good practice to use assertions in before() and after() functions? for example, if I want to test create function by describe('create object1 & object2', function { it('create object1'); it('create object2'); } ); , now what if i want to test the destroy function? should i add it('delete object1 and object2'); where i assert deletion or put the deletion functionality in after(); and assert the deletion of object1&object2 in the after function?

Comment: It does make sense to put assertions into `before` and `after` hooks to make sure that your test setup is in a consistent state. Note that Mocha takes a failure in any hook as a fatal failure and will stop any further testing.